# Canonical morphism from $\operatorname{ran}_{(\operatorname{lan}_{f} 1_X)} 1_B$ to $f: X \to B$

Tags: category-theory, kan-extensions

For a given morphism $f: X \to B$, and assuming the extensions exist, does the canonical 2-morphism $ \operatorname{ran}_{(\operatorname{lan}_{f} 1_X)} 1_B \Rightarrow f$ has a conventional name ?

The same question could be asked for $ f \to \operatorname{lift}_{(\operatorname{rift}_f 1_B)} 1_X$

Comment: I am a bit rusty on this, but assuming existence is not a problem, $\text{lan}_f1$ is the right adjoint of $f$ (and the extension is absolute); call it $g$; $\text{ran}_g 1$ is the left adjoint of $g$, so you get back $f$, and the canonical morphism $ \operatorname{ran}_{(\operatorname{lan}_{f} 1_X)} 1_B \Rightarrow f$ is invertible. Similary, for $ f \to \operatorname{lift}_{(\operatorname{rift}_f 1_B)} 1_X$ I think.

Comment: I think this *requires* that $fg$ is the extension of $f$ along itself (by absoluteness, or preservation) to get back the counit, and get the adjunction (I looked up Riehl's "context" prop 6.5.2 p211 to get a refresher). of course if we have an adjunction to begin with, we also get an iso. that said, it would be good to have names for fundamental iso (not claiming this is one)

Comment: Oh yes. You are right, you probably need to require that $f$ preserves $\text{lan}_f1$ and then you also have that the extension is absolute.